# Check property in respondsToSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, selector

I have Protocol

```
@protocol ListPickerCellDelegate <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, strong) TAActivity *activity;
@end
```

I want to check delegate on its property. How canI do it?

My code, not sure is it ok

```
if (!self.delegate || ![self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(activity))]) {

}
```

Comment: What does "check delegate on its property" mean?

Comment: it means have my delegate its property or not

Comment: I think you meant if(self.delegate && [self.delegate responds....]) but the whole point of using a protocol is that you don't need to do this. The compiler will tell you if your delegate does provide mandatory properties.

Comment: @MichaelL The method can be optional … But in his example it is not. This makes no sense.

Comment: @MatDemon In your sample, the property (its methods) is required. You do not have to check for the existence at all. If it is an optional property, please add that to your snippet.

Comment: yes, this property may be optimal, so I need to add this checking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments:

You only have to check for the existence of the implementation, if

- the property is optional *or*
- you get an instance and do not know, whether its class implements the protocol.

If this is the case:

First let me rewrite this applying [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if(!(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(activity)]))
{
   …
}
```

I do not really understand this, because you check, whether there is *no* method `activity`? Usually it is the other way round and you want to know, whether it is there in advance of using it.

However, if `self.delegate` is `nil`, `[self.delegate respondsToSelector:…]` will return `NO` (defined message to nil behavior) and the whole `&&` expression will evaluate to `NO` regardless of the first condition. So it is pointless to check for `nil`.

Just write:

```
if(![self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(activity)])
{
   // Do not use activity
}
else 
{
  TAActivity *activity = [self.delegate activity];
}
```

(I really would turn that around.)

Answer (score -2):

Just check if `activity` is NULL

Comment: This will cause an exception, if `-activity` is not implemented. The whole Q is strange.

Comment: Yea i thought it was rather strange too. Guess I should have stated that. If its not implemented he won't have to "check" for it, because it will throw an error. I figured his question was more about if it had been initialized.